# I am passing an instance of a WebDriver to a parent class with super() keyword, but yet I'm getting nullpointerexeption

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, inheritance

my code looks in the next way:

Parent class:

```
package TestPackageForStructure;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;

public class PageElements {

    WebDriver driver;

    public PageElements(WebDriver driver) {
        this.driver = driver;
    }

    WebElement searchBox = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"APjFqb\"]"));

}
```

Child class:

```
package TestPackageForStructure;

import io.qameta.allure.Step;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;

public class PageSteps extends PageElements {

    public PageSteps(WebDriver driver) {
        super(driver);
    }

    @Step
    public void inputData(String text) {
        searchBox.sendKeys("Hello");
    }
```

Test class:

```
import TestPackageForStructure.PageSteps;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

public class TestStructure {

    @Test
    public void insertSomeData() throws InterruptedException {
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
        PageSteps pageSteps = new PageSteps(driver);

        driver.get("https://www.google.com/");
        Thread.sleep(5000);
        pageSteps.inputData("Hello World");

    }

}
```

Error:
java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver.findElement(org.openqa.selenium.By)" because "this.driver" is null

So to say it shortly, I'm throwing my instance of a WebDriver to a parent class by using the super keyword in the child constructor but the driver is still null

I was expecting the driver to be passed to a parent class and an instance of WebElement to be created without any daviations (driver not being null)

Answer (score 2):

I believe this should fix your code:

```
WebElement searchBox;
public PageElements(WebDriver driver) {
    this.driver = driver;
    searchBox = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"APjFqb\"]"));
}
```

The problem you are having is that `driver` is not set yet the way you are doing it.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the reply, it really did help ^^ More than the solution, I want to understand why Java is behaving like that because there are lots of solutions.. F.e. if I create a method in the PageElements class that returns that SpecificElement, it works also ... I'm just confused about how java behaves.. I did the same with the integers with different classes and got more confused.. :D

Comment: But now it does not find an element.. :D

Comment: Re: " I want to understand why Java is behaving like that..." because it is part of the programming language specification. You can find resources on the internet to get a full step by step explanation of what happens when you create a new object in Java. But for now, can you please click the check mark by my answer to mark this question answered?

Comment: I'd also be curious what the problem was and how your code fixes it. Just pointing at the langspec is a poor answer. Is is because in the original code the `WebElement searchBox = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"APjFqb\"]"));` runs before the constructor is called?

Comment: Not really helpful answer to be honest :) The problem is still there, now the element cant be located, that's why this community exists to ask questions and not to redirect to manuals that are scattered all over the internet :) I could not find some answers and that is why this question is still here

Comment: @Robert Most probably I have that suspicion.. That the value is assigned before the constructor is called...

Answer (score 2):

The fields of a class are initialised before the constructor(s). Here is a simple example which demonstrates - I've swapped `WebDriver` for `String`, and added a few println to show values. These ought to be executed in order 1,2,3,4:

```
class PageElements {

    { System.out.println("1 "+this); }
    String driver ; //= "this";

    public PageElements(String driver) {
        this.driver = driver;
        System.out.println("3 "+this);
    }

    // At this point driver is still null
    { System.out.println("2 "+this); }
    int searchBox = driver.length();

    public String toString() {
        return "PageElements[driver="+driver+" searchBox="+searchBox+']';
    }
    public static void main(String... args) {
        System.out.println("4 "+new PageElements("this and that"));
    }
}
```

The field value `searchBox` is initialised when driver is null - hence your `NullPointerException` and you will see the output:

```
1 PageElements[driver=null searchBox=0]
2 PageElements[driver=null searchBox=0]
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "String.length()" because "this.driver" is null
```

Change the declaration of `driver` to `String driver = "this";` and it will print 1,2,3,4 showing that searchBox is defined using the old value "this":

```
1 PageElements[driver=null searchBox=0]
2 PageElements[driver=this searchBox=0]
3 PageElements[driver=this and that searchBox=4]
4 PageElements[driver=this and that searchBox=4]
```

So, the answer by ControlAltDel shows the correct way to initialise `searchBox`. Making both fields `final` and set in constructor may help.

Comment: Thanks a lot :) Only have one question,  { System.out.println("1 "+this); }  in this line how does "this" keyword behave? Does not it only point at the driver itself? how did it invoke toString() method?

Comment: The value of `this` is the current instance of a class, and any String concatenation implicitly calls `String.valueOf(Object obj)` which itself returns `(obj == null) ? "null" : obj.toString()`. So `"1 "+this` is same as `"1 "+this.toString()`, and the toString call I added retrieves the value of each member field.